# сумма строк в выборке с WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

Допустим, есть такой запрос, который выводит количество строк по каждому фильтру:

```
SELECT (`delivery`), COUNT(*) 
FROM prod_data 
WHERE `delivery` = 'Евросоюз Cream' OR `delivery` = 'Cream BetaPost' 
GROUP BY `delivery`
```

Вопрос: как можно посчитать сумму количества строк по вышеуказанной выборке?

Comment: @Legionary зачем такая бессмысленная правка?  cruim - а вы зачем-то её еще и принимаете

Comment: @АлексейШиманский правка была внесена практически одновременно с тобой, на момент нажатия "править" правок внесено не было. После нажатия "Сохранить изменения" - сообщение было отражено с твоей правкой. Но и моя отправлена уже была. Мои исправления были не только "кол-во" но и форматирование кода (относительно начального варианта). Твоя правка на тот момент никак не была отражена.

Comment: @Legionary ок. Выяснили.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можете считать количество без группировки, фактически получится та же сумма:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM prod_data 
WHERE `delivery` = 'Евросоюз Cream' OR `delivery` = 'Cream BetaPost'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(x) FROM ((
    SELECT COUNT(*) as x
    FROM prod_data 
    WHERE `delivery` = 'Евросоюз Cream' OR `delivery` = 'Cream BetaPost' 
    GROUP BY `delivery`
) as prom)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (`delivery`), COUNT(*) 
FROM prod_data   
WHERE `delivery` IN ( 'Евросоюз Cream', 'Cream BetaPost' )
GROUP BY `delivery` 
WITH ROLLUP
```